# Is it possible to replace the 'Add to cart' with 'ask for an estimate' button in Magento?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to build an ecommerce website based on Magento but having a regular shop behaviour, instead of showing product prices, i want visitors to ask for an estimate for a single or several products (by adding them to a cart and then asking for a global estimate).

As a store manager, I should get these estimate requests by email along with customer information (name, email, phone, company, address .. )

Is this achievable with Magento?

If not, which cms/platform would be best suitable for such a project?

Comment: While it's easy to replace the add to cart button by editing the template files (could even use a product attribute as a switch), the rest sounds like you may want to make a custom extension and base it off the wishlist behavior. I haven't looked into doing it myself but it certainly is possible.

Comment: Did you try this ? Looks like https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html this can help

Answer (score 0):

Not without some customization. You could put all your products in with a price of $0 and then change your theme so all the buttons say "request a quote" and the price isn't displayed anywhere. Then the checkout page might not ask for credit card info, but I'm not certain about that. If it did you would have to remove that part of the checkout module. Once a user finished checking out you would get an email with all their information. I don't think this is the best way to go about getting what you want though.

I don't know if other ecommerce platforms have what you are looking for. I'm not very familiar with them beyond Magento. But you could certainly use something like drupal or wordpress to build a site and have a request a quote form on it. This would only be managable with a small number of products though.

Answer (score 0):

there is many extension available for this type features.[link 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price.html%E2%80%8E)
[link 2](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/call-for-price.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,

This extension : [**link**](http://www.cart2quote.com/) does precisely what i was looking for.